# Automatically displaying node labels in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

The CoDi package has a `prompter` feature which, when enabled, puts every node inside a box, labelling them with their object names (see page 8 of the [CoDi manual](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/commutative-diagrams/commutative-diagrams-doc.pdf#page=8)):

[image]

Is it possible to make `tikz-cd` do something similar, labelling non-empty nodes in a diagram by their grid position?

---

**Example:** such an option should transform the diagram

[image]
(source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep={4.5em,between origins}, column sep={4.5em,between origins}, ampersand replacement=\&]
    \&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrrd]
    \&\&\&\&
    \\
    \&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrru]
    \&\&\&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rddd]
    \&
    \\
    \&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rdd]
    \arrow[ruu]
    \&\&\&\&\&
    \\
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrru]
    \arrow[ruu]
    \&\&\&\&\&\&\&\&
    \\
    \&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrrr]
    \&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \\
    \&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrrr]
    \arrow[luuuu]
    \&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rddd,bend right]
    \arrow[rddd,bend left]
    \arrow[ruuuu]
    \&\&
    \\
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrrd]
    \arrow[uuu]
    \&\&\&\&\&\&\&\&
    \\
    \&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[ruuu]\&\&\&\&\&
    \\
    \&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrrd]
    \arrow[luu]
    \arrow[ruuu]
    \&\&\&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[ruuuu]
    \&
    \\
    \&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[luu,bend right]
    \arrow[luu,bend left]
    \arrow[rrru]
    \&\&\&\&
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

)
into the diagram:

[image]

(source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep={4.5em,between origins}, column sep={4.5em,between origins},ampersand replacement=\&]
    \&\&\&\&
    \boxed{\bullet}_{\text{1-5}}
    \arrow[rrrd]
    \&\&\&\&
    \\
    \&
    \boxed{\bullet}_{\text{2-2}}
    \arrow[rrru]
    \&\&\&\&\&\&
    \boxed{\bullet}_{\text{2-8}}
    \arrow[rddd]
    \&
    \\
    \&\&\&
    \boxed{\bullet}_{\text{3-4}}
    \arrow[rdd]
    \arrow[ruu]
    \&\&\&\&\&
    \\
    \boxed{\bullet}_{\text{4-1}}
    \arrow[rrru]
    \arrow[ruu]
    \&\&\&\&\&\&\&\&
    \\
    \&\&\&\&
    \boxed{\bullet}_{\text{5-5}}
    \arrow[rrrr]
    \&\&\&\&
    \boxed{\bullet}_{\text{5-9}}
    \\
    \&\&
    \boxed{\bullet}_{\text{6-3}}
    \arrow[rrrr]
    \arrow[luuuu]
    \&\&\&\&
    \boxed{\bullet}_{\text{6-7}}
    \arrow[rddd,bend right]
    \arrow[rddd,bend left]
    \arrow[ruuuu]
    \&\&
    \\
    \boxed{\bullet}_{\text{7-1}}
    \arrow[rrrd]
    \arrow[uuu]
    \&\&\&\&\&\&\&\&
    \\
    \&\&\&
    \boxed{\bullet}_{\text{8-4}}
    \arrow[ruuu]\&\&\&\&\&
    \\
    \&
    \boxed{\bullet}_{\text{9-2}}
    \arrow[rrrd]
    \arrow[luu]
    \arrow[ruuu]
    \&\&\&\&\&\&
    \boxed{\bullet}_{\text{9-8}}
    \arrow[ruuuu]
    \&
    \\
    \&\&\&\&
    \boxed{\bullet}_{\text{10-5}}
    \arrow[luu,bend right]
    \arrow[luu,bend left]
    \arrow[rrru]
    \&\&\&\&
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

)

Comment: I try to understand the labeling shouldn´t the coordinate 2-1 actually be 2-2 and 2-7 be 2-8 because it is on the level of 9-2 and 9-8 respectively?

Comment: Yes, these are mistakes. I've corrected them now. Thanks and sorry for the error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not my answer but by a friend. The important information seems to be that the row and column indices are stored in the TeX counts `\pgfmatrixcurrentrow` and `\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn`, respectively. One can then use those to autolabel the nonempty cells.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep={4.5em,between origins}, 
    column sep={4.5em,between origins}, ampersand replacement=\&,
    nodes in empty cells=false,
    cells={
    nodes={draw,
        execute at end node={%
            \makebox[0pt][l]{$~~{}_{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}$}}
        }
        }
        ]
    \&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrrd]
    \&\&\&\&
    \\
    \&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrru]
    \&\&\&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rddd]
    \&
    \\
    \&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rdd]
    \arrow[ruu]
    \&\&\&\&\&
    \\
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrru]
    \arrow[ruu]
    \&\&\&\&\&\&\&\&
    \\
    \&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrrr]
    \&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \\
    \&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrrr]
    \arrow[luuuu]
    \&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rddd,bend right]
    \arrow[rddd,bend left]
    \arrow[ruuuu]
    \&\&
    \\
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrrd]
    \arrow[uuu]
    \&\&\&\&\&\&\&\&
    \\
    \&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[ruuu]\&\&\&\&\&
    \\
    \&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrrd]
    \arrow[luu]
    \arrow[ruuu]
    \&\&\&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[ruuuu]
    \&
    \\
    \&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[luu,bend right]
    \arrow[luu,bend left]
    \arrow[rrru]
    \&\&\&\&
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is beyond wonderful! (Please send my thanks also to your friend :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a very small variation on user237902's answer: using `\tikzcdset`, one can create keys `prompter` and `prompter all` as in

```
\tikzcdset{%
    prompter/.code={%
        \tikzset{%
            nodes in empty cells=false,cells={nodes={draw,execute at end node={\makebox[0pt][l]{$~~{}_{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}$}}}}
        }%
    }%
}%
\tikzcdset{%
    prompter all/.code={%
        \tikzset{%
            nodes in empty cells=true,cells={nodes={draw,execute at end node={\makebox[0pt][l]{$~~{}_{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}$}}}}
        }%
    }%
}%
```

to be able to call this feature in `\begin{tikzcd}` as `\begin{tikzcd}[prompter]`. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{%
    prompter/.code={%
        \tikzset{%
            nodes in empty cells=false,cells={nodes={draw,execute at end node={\makebox[0pt][l]{$~~{}_{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}$}}}}
        }%
    }%
}%
\tikzcdset{%
    prompter all/.code={%
        \tikzset{%
            nodes in empty cells=true,cells={nodes={draw,execute at end node={\makebox[0pt][l]{$~~{}_{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}$}}}}
        }%
    }%
}%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep={4.5em,between origins},column sep={4.5em,between origins}, ampersand replacement=\&,prompter]%
    \&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrrd]
    \&\&\&\&
    \\
    \&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrru]
    \&\&\&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rddd]
    \&
    \\
    \&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rdd]
    \arrow[ruu]
    \&\&\&\&\&
    \\
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrru]
    \arrow[ruu]
    \&\&\&\&\&\&\&\&
    \\
    \&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrrr]
    \&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \\
    \&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrrr]
    \arrow[luuuu]
    \&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rddd,bend right]
    \arrow[rddd,bend left]
    \arrow[ruuuu]
    \&\&
    \\
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrrd]
    \arrow[uuu]
    \&\&\&\&\&\&\&\&
    \\
    \&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[ruuu]\&\&\&\&\&
    \\
    \&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrrd]
    \arrow[luu]
    \arrow[ruuu]
    \&\&\&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[ruuuu]
    \&
    \\
    \&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[luu,bend right]
    \arrow[luu,bend left]
    \arrow[rrru]
    \&\&\&\&
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

generates
[image]

while the same code but with `prompter` replaced with `prompter all` gives
[image]
Of course, the latter is quite ugly, but this feature might be useful depending on the diagram.

A further aesthetic variation is to change the keys `prompter` and `prompter all` to the following:

```
\tikzcdset{%
    prompter/.code={%
        \tikzset{%
            nodes in empty cells=false,cells={nodes={draw,execute at end node={\makebox[0pt][l]{$~{}_{%
                \smash{%
                    \raisebox{-0.75em}{
                        \colorbox{OIblue}{%
                            \textcolor{white}{%
                                \textbf{\textsf{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}}%
                            }%
                        }%
                    }%
                }%
            }$}}}}%
        }%
    }%
}%
\tikzcdset{%
    prompter all/.code={%
        \tikzset{%
            nodes in empty cells=true,cells={nodes={draw,execute at end node={\makebox[0pt][l]{$~{}_{%
                \smash{%
                    \raisebox{-0.75em}{
                        \colorbox{OIblue}{%
                            \textcolor{white}{%
                                \textbf{\textsf{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}}%
                            }%
                        }%
                    }%
                }%
            }$}}}}%
        }%
    }%
}%
```

(the first of) which gives
[image]

Here's a MWE for the above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{OIblue}{RGB}{0,114,178}
\tikzcdset{%
    prompter/.code={%
        \tikzset{%
            nodes in empty cells=false,cells={nodes={draw,execute at end node={\makebox[0pt][l]{$~{}_{%
                \smash{%
                    \raisebox{-0.75em}{
                        \colorbox{OIblue}{%
                            \textcolor{white}{%
                                \textbf{\textsf{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}}%
                            }%
                        }%
                    }%
                }%
            }$}}}}%
        }%
    }%
}%
\tikzcdset{%
    prompter all/.code={%
        \tikzset{%
            nodes in empty cells=true,cells={nodes={draw,execute at end node={\makebox[0pt][l]{$~{}_{%
                \smash{%
                    \raisebox{-0.75em}{
                        \colorbox{OIblue}{%
                            \textcolor{white}{%
                                \textbf{\textsf{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}}%
                            }%
                        }%
                    }%
                }%
            }$}}}}%
        }%
    }%
}%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep={4.5em,between origins},column sep={4.5em,between origins}, ampersand replacement=\&,prompter]%
    \&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrrd]
    \&\&\&\&
    \\
    \&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrru]
    \&\&\&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rddd]
    \&
    \\
    \&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rdd]
    \arrow[ruu]
    \&\&\&\&\&
    \\
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrru]
    \arrow[ruu]
    \&\&\&\&\&\&\&\&
    \\
    \&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrrr]
    \&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \\
    \&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrrr]
    \arrow[luuuu]
    \&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rddd,bend right]
    \arrow[rddd,bend left]
    \arrow[ruuuu]
    \&\&
    \\
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrrd]
    \arrow[uuu]
    \&\&\&\&\&\&\&\&
    \\
    \&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[ruuu]\&\&\&\&\&
    \\
    \&
    \bullet
    \arrow[rrrd]
    \arrow[luu]
    \arrow[ruuu]
    \&\&\&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[ruuuu]
    \&
    \\
    \&\&\&\&
    \bullet
    \arrow[luu,bend right]
    \arrow[luu,bend left]
    \arrow[rrru]
    \&\&\&\&
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It may help if you provide a MWE.
Am I right that you want to label nodes according to their coordinates like in my example. Node 4-(-4) has the coordinates 4 and -4?

```
\documentclass[border=1.21cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \foreach\x/\y in {0/0,2/2,4/-4}
        \draw[] (\x,\y)  node[fill=white,draw=black,rectangle,inner sep=2pt] {\x-\y};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I edited the question to add the source of the diagrams there. I was thinking of having a flag like "show labels` (invoked as in `\begin{tikzpicture}[show labels]`) which would then add these modifications, leaving the code of the diagram itself unchanged.

Comment: The coordinates shown should agree with the internal `tikz-cd` coordinates; so your example would instead have coordinates "2-(2)"↦"1-2", "0-(0)" ↦ "2-1", and "4-(-4)"↦"4-3" (assuming if it were drawn using `tikz-cd` it would be a diagram involving four rows and three columns)

Comment: The idea is to be able to draw arrows at the end of the code, after all nodes are entered, using e.g. `\arrow[from=1-1,to=3-3,"f"]` instead of placing `\arrow[rrdd,"f"]` together with the nodes

Comment: The coordinate system I'm using is the one the `tikz-cd` manual refers to as the "diagram matrix" in [Section 2.3 there](https://texdoc.org/serve/tikz-cd/0#page=8).